# Plotting proportional data derived from numeric in Python

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` containing ages for students and non students, which looks something like this:

```
Subject    Student    Age
001        yes        21
002        yes        45
003        no         61
004        no         37
...
```

I would like to plot the proportions of each group under the age of 40. I can do this in R with `plot(factor(age < 40) ~ Student, data = df)` which gives me:

[image]

Is there a way to replicate this in Python, ideally using either matplotlib or seaborn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt option to create such plot. You may create it through matplotlib of course by calculating the respecting numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.poisson(lam=40, size=6000)
b = ((a>50).astype(int)+np.random.rand(6000))>0.9
df = pd.DataFrame({"Subject" : np.arange(6000),
                   "Age" : a, "Student" : b})

df["Age>40"] = df["Age"] > 40

def propplot(x, y, data):
    xdata = data[[x,y]].groupby(x)
    xcount = xdata.count()

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(xcount), 
                             gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":list(xcount[y].values)})
    for ax, (n,grp) in zip(axes, xdata):

        ycount = grp.groupby(y).count().T
        ycount /= float(ycount.values.sum())
        ycount.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, width=1, legend=False)
        ax.set_xlabel(n)
        ax.set_xlim(-.5,.5)
        ax.set_ylim(0,1)
        ax.set_xticks([])
    axes[0].set_ylabel(y)
    axes[0].legend(ncol=100, title=y, loc=(0,1.02))
    fig.text(0.5,0.02, x)

propplot("Student", "Age>40", df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed!